# SQL Like %>=value

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I do this in SQL

```
select * from table where price_table like %(>=200)
```

if I have a (USD 250, IDR 2000) in the fields `price_table`?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What is the exact type of the `price_table` column?

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing that you have a price field that is a string with the first 3 characters as the currency, followed by a space, and then the number.

If so, you can do:

```
where substr(price_table, 5) + 0 >= 200
```

However, the real solution is to break the column into two columns, one for the currency and the other for the amount.  Then such a query would be simpler.

Comment: I don't believe this query would be sargable, which may have performance implications.

Answer (score 0):

`"USD 250"` is a *rendering* of two values, one an *amount* and the other a *currency*.

Best practice, and indeed [*First Normal Form*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), says store only one value in a column.

IMHO, the "correct" answer is that you should create 2 columns, eg `price_amount` and `price_currency`, split your multi-value `price_table` column into them, then delete the `price_table` column.

After doing this, your query becomes simple and the solution obvious.